# Is there a way to get the equation for two or more waves that have been added together

Tags: trigonometry, differential-geometry, trigonometric-series

I have wave which I'd like to find the equation for which is obviously the result of adding two waves together.

I have tried using Lagrange Interpolation to some success however I was wondering if there was a way to extract the equation for which waves were added to make the wave in the first place.

This is my first time posting on here so I'm sorry if this is in any way not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sum of two wave in the form of
$$
y=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)
$$
then, $y$ can be written as
$$
y=A\cos(x-\delta).
$$
In fact, expanding the last equation as
$$
A\cos(x-\delta)=A\Big(\cos(x)\cos(\delta)+\sin(x)\sin(\delta)\Big)
$$
the equivalence is guarantee if $A^2=a^2+b^2$ as well $a=A\cos(\delta)$ and $b=A\sin(\delta)$.

Comment: Sorry I meant that I have the sum of two waves as actual waves.

As in I have the coordinates of these waves and can graph them hence finding there attributes but I want to find something akin to y=acos(x)+bsin(x)